# Writing loops with i++ or ++i

Tags: c++, c

I have a question about writing loops. I always begin with

```
(int i=0; i<10; i++)
```

But I see many experts begin with

```
(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
```

**Is there there any real difference, or they are same?**

Of course, I know the difference between pre-increment and post-increment. I mean which one I should use when writing the loop? or it depends.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference among the two. Pre increment and post increment are the only 
difference.

The difference between `i++` and `++i` is the value of the expression.

The value `i++` is the value of `i` before the increment. The value of `++i` is the value of `i` after the increment.

However in your loop it does not make any difference.

```
int i = 0;
00000088  xor         edx,edx 
0000008a  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],edx 
            i++;
0000008d  inc         dword ptr [ebp-40h] 
            ++i;
00000090  inc         dword ptr [ebp-40h]
```

As you can see it does not make any difference in performance but in certain situations you might want to increment a number right after a sequence point or before it.

In C++ `++i` is an l-value, but `i++` is not.

Comment: Why did people down vote this...?

Comment: I have no idea - this has been happening with me so often.

Comment: There's no difference in this case (with int) but there is with other types which is why preincrement is preferred.

Comment: @Acme:  This website is always quick to jump on votes (up or down).  I've seen so many wrong answers be up-voted just because they posted a right fact (and not a right answer).

Comment: Dunno SO was not like this before.

Comment: That was because the community was smaller and stronger.  Now it's full of Reddit-esque users.

Comment: Note the question is tagged C++ so there **is** a difference

Comment: @Mark, the issue was as why people were down-voting and you're the first to post why...

Comment: I downvoted because while what you say is true, it doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: It does - there is *no* difference in performance. Please see the assembly code.

Comment: Rereading the question, strictly speaking you do answer it. I don't think you fully answer it though, there is a reason 'many experts' prefer preincrement and I feel a complete answer should mention that.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ there is a difference. While the prefix operator will return a reference to the value, the postfix operator will return a copy and therefore is slower than the prefix operator.

Comment: Only if the type of `i` is user-defined and its `operator++` is not inlined.

Comment: For many primitive types any decent compiler will optimize away this perceived performance hit.  For more complex types this could be true.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between pre- and post-incrementing lies in the return value.
Post-incrementing returns the value which has been present before the variable has been increased, essentially creating a copy of the old value. Pre-incrementing returns a reference to the new value, thereby avoiding the creation of a temporary variable.
Generally speaking it does not make a difference and is mostly a matter of taste, but in certain cases where memory is short the pre-increment option might be more useful. I also read that the post-increment version is supposed to be slower (as it creates a new temporary variable) but I have not found any conclusive proof of that

Answer (score 0):

Preincrement is generally preferred because while it makes no difference for primitive types it may be faster for iterators as preincrement doesn't have to return a copy of its old value.

Since preincrement is sometimes faster (with non primitive types like iterators) it is a good habit to get into even where it makes no performance difference which is why many people recommend it. This is item 28 in [C++ Coding Standards](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586) for example.

Comment: In *this case*, what semantic difference is there?

Comment: There is no difference in this case but the question was why 'many experts' prefer preincrement and the answer is because it makes a difference in some cases and so it is a good habit to get into even for the cases where it doesn't.